# Map functions and regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to get the domain from a list of URL's. For that, I'm using regex in a function for pattern matching.

```
def get_domain(url):
    m  = re.search(r"https:\/\/(.*)\/", url)
    result = m.group(1)
    return result;
string_array = ("hTTps://stack0verflow.com/", "hTTps://stackoverfl0w.com/", "hTTps://stackoverfiow.com/")
m = list(map(get_domain, string_array))
```

The function get_domain works if I use a for-loop to iterate over the list of strings, but whenever I try to use the map function, I get the error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-575cbcab950e> in <module>
      9     print(get_domain(url))
     10 
---> 11 m = list(map(get_domain, string_array))
     12 ##print(m)

<ipython-input-19-fc11e511d74d> in get_domain(url)
     12 def get_domain(url):
     13     m  = re.search(r"https:\/\/(.*)\/", url)
---> 14     result = m.group(1)
     15     return result;

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong? I've seen a lot of examples online of the map function, and I think i have the syntax down.

Comment: You are not accounting for the case when your regex does not match `url`. In this case `m` is `None` and hence has no attribute `group` as indicated by the error message.

Comment: you are using hTTps in the urls, but trying to match https, use re.IGNORECASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex will get only domain name in first group :

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|ssh).)?((?=.*\.)[^\n\/]*)
```

**and don't forget to make it case insensitive**

exemple :

```
import re

arr = ["https://www.exemple.com/?query=blablabla","https://www.exemple.com/aaa","hTTp://www.exemple.com","www.exemple.com/aaa","exemple.com"]
for i in arr:
    m = re.search(r"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|ssh).)?((?=.*\.)[^\n\/]*)",i,re.IGNORECASE)
    print(m.group(1))
```